# Is there a way to write this using a String array instead of an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, permutation

I'm studying permutation. I found this algorithm but I don't fully understand what is happening within the array list. I tried rewriting it using a String array but was unsuccessful.

```
public static ArrayList<String> combinations(String nChars, int k) 
    {
        int n = nChars.length();
        ArrayList<String> combos = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (k == 0) 
        {
            combos.add("");
            return combos;
        }
        if (n < k || n == 0)
            return combos;
        String last = nChars.substring(n-1);
        combos.addAll(combinations(nChars.substring(0, n-1), k));
        for (String subCombo : combinations(nChars.substring(0, n-1), k-1)) 
            combos.add(subCombo + last);

        return combos;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String nChars = "ABCDEF";
        System.out.println(combinations(nChars, 4));
    }
```

Comment: Please choose a suitable title for the question

Comment: what error are you getting and yes make sure to choose suitable title.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and what you expect the output to be? There is quite a bit of recursion in this.

Answer (score 3):

The provided code uses an ArrayList over a classic String[] (String array) because ArrayLists have a dynamic size as well as convenient methods for appending, changing, and removing elements without having to worry about exceeding the size of the array. If you'd like to learn more, here is the Java documentation for [ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

The reason you are getting an error on replacing the ArrayList with a vanilla array is because the array itself has none of the methods (e.g. `combos.add(subCombo + last);`) that are defined by ArrayList. If you want to replace the ArrayList with an array, you'd have to perform the corresponding actions manually.

EDIT: I am an idiot and didn't read the question title. While it technically would be possible to rewrite this using a String array, it would require us to know how many possible combinations we might add to our `combos` array so we can allocate the appropriate amount of space (i.e. `String[] combos = new String[num]`). Computing `num` would either be tedious, or allocate too much space to the array, using up uneccesary amounts of memory. Best to leave the memory management to the ArrayList and worry about the actual problem at hand most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

> combos.addAll(combinations(nChars.substring(0, n-1), k));

This call shows the major difference between arrays and implementations of the List interface

- first, you can call methods on a List
- secondly, you don't need to worry about the **size** of that data structure

In other words: to *rewrite* your code to use a pure array, **you** have to keep track of the current size of the array, and when you add new entries you have to **increase** the size of your array. By doing all the things that the ArrayList implicitly does for you: allocating a new array, copying over all old entries, to then finally put in the new ones you intend to add.